# Long to wide format BUT with duplicities and counts (classic R)

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (example):

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  10  a  K  2 90
2  10  b  K  1 90
3  10  c  L  1 50
4  10  c  Q  1 70
5  10  d  Q  2 70
6  10  e  K  3 90
7  10  e  L  2 50
8  10  e  Q  4 70
9  20  f  K  1 75
10 20  g  K  2 75
11 20  g  Q  1 80
12 20  h  L  1 30
```

and I would need to transform it into:

```
10, a, K=2, L=0, Q=0, P1=90, P2=50, P3=70
10, b, K=1, L=0, Q=0, P1=90, P2=50, P3=70
10, c, K=1, L=0, Q=1, P1=90, P2=50, P3=70
10, d, K=0, L=0, Q=2, P1=90, P2=50, P3=70
10, e, K=3, L=2, Q=4, P1=90, P2=50, P3=70
20, f, K=1, L=0, Q=0, P1=75, P2=30, P3=80
20, g, K=2, L=0, Q=1, P1=75, P2=30, P3=80
20, h, K=0, L=1, Q=0, P1=75, P2=30, P3=80
```

Where "K=" etc. is omitted. Just to show required values.

**The rules are**

- No duplicities in V2.
- As many columns as many unique values of V3.
- In new matrix: Each column connected to unique value from V3 gets the relevant numbers from V4.
- In new matrix: Each duplicated column from previous point gets the relevant number from V5.

What I have right now: I have tried to look into previous questions but I have found no sufficient way how to transform it properly. I know the dimensionality of second matrix: `ncol = 2 + 2*length(unique(V3))` and `nrow = length(unique(V2))`. So I thought I could go with FOR cyclus... But had to discard this thought as I am really not sure how to account for these different lengths.

Then I have tried to separate it step by step... First separate block for values `V1 = 10`, get the "middle man", then find out the duplicities, but here I stopped once again since I did not know how to account for them properly.

I am searching for the **most elegant solution** first, but I would also like to find a **computationally fast** one as well. The *best solution* would contain **only classic R functions** (However, if there is nothing which could solve it elegantly, sophisticated packages could be ok as well).

What the R gives me for dput(dta):

```
structure(list(V1 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 
20, 20), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("K", "L", "Q"), class = "factor"), 
    V4 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1), V5 = c(90, 90, 
    50, 70, 70, 90, 50, 70, 75, 75, 80, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you can include your sample data using `dput()`, it will be less work for people to try out solutions, and it will avoid any ambiguities about code structure.

Comment: You refer to "matrix" for your input and output, but in R a `matrix` is a specific kind of data format, which is a rectangular grid of data *all of the same type*. Yours seems to be a mix of character and numeric data. Are you using `data.frame`s?

Comment: Included dput and changed to data frame

Comment: Your dput data is different (for instance in V5) than your table and desired output. Which should we use?

Comment: @JonSpring Sorry... The dput was wrong, I will try to edit it in next 40 minutes. 1) I want just values (therefore, excluding "P1=")... 2) The desired output is another dataframe with values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible (and possibly unwanted) `dplyr` way using pivoting:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  pivot_wider(c(V1, V2), 
              names_from = "V3",
              values_from = "V4",
              values_fill = 0) |>
  left_join(df |> 
              pivot_wider(c(V1, V2), 
                          names_from = "V3", 
                          values_from = "V5") |> 
              group_by(V1) |>
                fill(3:5, .direction = "downup") |>
              ungroup() |>
              select(V1, V2, P1 = K, P2 = L, P3 = Q),
            by = c("V1", "V2"))
```

**Output:**

```r
# A tibble: 8 × 8
     V1 V2        K     L     Q    P1    P2    P3
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10 a         2     0     0    90    50    70
2    10 b         1     0     0    90    50    70
3    10 c         0     1     1    90    50    70
4    10 d         0     0     2    90    50    70
5    10 e         3     2     4    90    50    70
6    20 f         1     0     0    75    30    80
7    20 g         2     0     1    75    30    80
8    20 h         0     1     0    75    30    80
```

**Adjusted data (corresponding to post):**

```r
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 
                      20, 20), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"
                                                ), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                       2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("K", "L", "Q"), class = "factor"), 
               V4 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1), V5 = c(90, 90, 
                                                                  50, 70, 70, 90, 50, 70, 75, 75, 80, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Update:** Using a `left_join` in instead of a `bind_cols`, probably safer.